# coreclr build fails on ubuntu 14.4 x64

Tags: ubuntu, coreclr

I am attempting to build coreclr on my ubuntu 14.4 vm using these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install git cmake clang-3.5 make llvm-3.5 gcc
git clone https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr
cd coreclr
./build.sh
```

The error I get is:

Invoking cmake with arguments: "/home/jon/coreclr" DEBUG
CMake Error at src/ToolBox/SOS/lldbplugin/CMakeLists.txt:24 (message):
  Cannot find lldb-3.5 or lldb-3.6.  Try installing lldb-3.6-dev (or the
  appropriate package for your platform)

How can I get coreclr to build?

My CMakeOutput.log file follows.

---

```
The system is: Linux - 3.16.0-33-generic - x86_64
Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" succeeded.
Compiler: /usr/bin/clang-3.5 
Build flags: 
Id flags: 

The output was:
0


Compilation of the C compiler identification source "CMakeCCompilerId.c" produced "a.out"

The C compiler identification is Clang, found in "/home/jon/coreclr/bin/obj/Linux.x64.Debug/CMakeFiles/2.8.12.2/CompilerIdC/a.out"

Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" succeeded.
Compiler: /usr/bin/clang++-3.5 
Build flags: 
Id flags: 

The output was:
0


Compilation of the CXX compiler identification source "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" produced "a.out"

The CXX compiler identification is Clang, found in "/home/jon/coreclr/bin/obj/Linux.x64.Debug/CMakeFiles/2.8.12.2/CompilerIdCXX/a.out"

Determining if the C compiler works passed with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/jon/coreclr/bin/obj/Linux.x64.Debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:/usr/bin/make "cmTryCompileExec3109069071/fast"
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3109069071.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3109069071.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/jon/coreclr/bin/obj/Linux.x64.Debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/jon/coreclr/bin/obj/Linux.x64.Debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles 1
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3109069071.dir/testCCompiler.c.o
/usr/bin/clang-3.5   -Wall -std=c11    -o CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3109069071.dir/testCCompiler.c.o   -c /home/jon/coreclr/bin/obj/Linux.x64.Debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c
Linking C executable cmTryCompileExec3109069071
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3109069071.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/clang-3.5   -Wall -std=c11     CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3109069071.dir/testCCompiler.c.o  -o cmTryCompileExec3109069071 -rdynamic 
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/jon/coreclr/bin/obj/Linux.x64.Debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'


Detecting C compiler ABI info compiled with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/jon/coreclr/bin/obj/Linux.x64.Debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:/usr/bin/make "cmTryCompileExec594400377/fast"
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec594400377.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec594400377.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/jon/coreclr/bin/obj/Linux.x64.Debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/jon/coreclr/bin/obj/Linux.x64.Debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles 1
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec594400377.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o
/usr/bin/clang-3.5   -Wall -std=c11    -o CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec594400377.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o   -c /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeCCompilerABI.c
Linking C executable cmTryCompileExec594400377
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec594400377.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/clang-3.5   -Wall -std=c11   -v CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec594400377.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o  -o cmTryCompileExec594400377 -rdynamic  
Ubuntu clang version 3.5.0-4ubuntu2~trusty2 (tags/RELEASE_350/final) (based on LLVM 3.5.0)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8.2
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9.1
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8.2
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9.1
Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Selected multilib: .;@m64
 "/usr/bin/ld" -export-dynamic -z relro --hash-style=gnu --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o cmTryCompileExec594400377 /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/crtbegin.o -L/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8 -L/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../.. -L/usr/lib/llvm-3.5/bin/../lib -L/lib -L/usr/lib CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec594400377.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lc -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/crtend.o /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/jon/coreclr/bin/obj/Linux.x64.Debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'


Parsed C implicit link information from above output:
  link line regex: [^( *|.*[/\])(llvm-link-3\.5|([^/\]+-)?ld|collect2)[^/\]*( |$)]
  ignore line: [Change Dir: /home/jon/coreclr/bin/obj/Linux.x64.Debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp]
  ignore line: []
  ignore line: [Run Build Command:/usr/bin/make "cmTryCompileExec594400377/fast"]
  ignore line: [/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec594400377.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec594400377.dir/build]
  ignore line: [make[1]: Entering directory `/home/jon/coreclr/bin/obj/Linux.x64.Debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp']
  ignore line: [/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/jon/coreclr/bin/obj/Linux.x64.Debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles 1]
  ignore line: [Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec594400377.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o]
  ignore line: [/usr/bin/clang-3.5   -Wall -std=c11    -o CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec594400377.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o   -c /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeCCompilerABI.c]
  ignore line: [Linking C executable cmTryCompileExec594400377]
  ignore line: [/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec594400377.dir/link.txt --verbose=1]
  ignore line: [/usr/bin/clang-3.5   -Wall -std=c11   -v CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec594400377.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o  -o cmTryCompileExec594400377 -rdynamic  ]
  ignore line: [Ubuntu clang version 3.5.0-4ubuntu2~trusty2 (tags/RELEASE_350/final) (based on LLVM 3.5.0)]
  ignore line: [Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu]
  ignore line: [Thread model: posix]
  ignore line: [Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8]
  ignore line: [Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8.2]
  ignore line: [Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9]
  ignore line: [Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9.1]
  ignore line: [Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8]
  ignore line: [Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8.2]
  ignore line: [Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9]
  ignore line: [Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9.1]
  ignore line: [Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8]
  ignore line: [Candidate multilib: .]
  ignore line: [@m64]
  ignore line: [Selected multilib: .]
  ignore line: [@m64]
  link line: [ "/usr/bin/ld" -export-dynamic -z relro --hash-style=gnu --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o cmTryCompileExec594400377 /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/crtbegin.o -L/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8 -L/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../.. -L/usr/lib/llvm-3.5/bin/../lib -L/lib -L/usr/lib CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec594400377.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lc -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/crtend.o /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o]
    arg [/usr/bin/ld] ==> ignore
    arg [-export-dynamic] ==> ignore
    arg [-zrelro] ==> ignore
    arg [--hash-style=gnu] ==> ignore
    arg [--build-id] ==> ignore
    arg [--eh-frame-hdr] ==> ignore
    arg [-m] ==> ignore
    arg [elf_x86_64] ==> ignore
    arg [-dynamic-linker] ==> ignore
    arg [/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2] ==> ignore
    arg [-o] ==> ignore
    arg [cmTryCompileExec594400377] ==> ignore
    arg [/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o] ==> ignore
    arg [/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o] ==> ignore
    arg [/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/crtbegin.o] ==> ignore
    arg [-L/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8] ==> dir [/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8]
    arg [-L/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu] ==> dir [/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu]
    arg [-L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu] ==> dir [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu]
    arg [-L/lib/../lib64] ==> dir [/lib/../lib64]
    arg [-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu] ==> dir [/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu]
    arg [-L/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../..] ==> dir [/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../..]
    arg [-L/usr/lib/llvm-3.5/bin/../lib] ==> dir [/usr/lib/llvm-3.5/bin/../lib]
    arg [-L/lib] ==> dir [/lib]
    arg [-L/usr/lib] ==> dir [/usr/lib]
    arg [CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec594400377.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o] ==> ignore
    arg [-lgcc] ==> lib [gcc]
    arg [--as-needed] ==> ignore
    arg [-lgcc_s] ==> lib [gcc_s]
    arg [--no-as-needed] ==> ignore
    arg [-lc] ==> lib [c]
    arg [-lgcc] ==> lib [gcc]
    arg [--as-needed] ==> ignore
    arg [-lgcc_s] ==> lib [gcc_s]
    arg [--no-as-needed] ==> ignore
    arg [/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/crtend.o] ==> ignore
    arg [/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o] ==> ignore
  remove lib [gcc]
  remove lib [gcc_s]
  remove lib [gcc]
  remove lib [gcc_s]
  collapse library dir [/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8] ==> [/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8]
  collapse library dir [/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu] ==> [/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu]
  collapse library dir [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu] ==> [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu]
  collapse library dir [/lib/../lib64] ==> [/lib64]
  collapse library dir [/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu] ==> [/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu]
  collapse library dir [/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../..] ==> [/usr/lib]
  collapse library dir [/usr/lib/llvm-3.5/bin/../lib] ==> [/usr/lib/llvm-3.5/lib]
  collapse library dir [/lib] ==> [/lib]
  collapse library dir [/usr/lib] ==> [/usr/lib]
  implicit libs: [c]
  implicit dirs: [/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu;/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu;/lib64;/usr/lib;/usr/lib/llvm-3.5/lib;/lib]
  implicit fwks: []


Determining if the CXX compiler works passed with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/jon/coreclr/bin/obj/Linux.x64.Debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:/usr/bin/make "cmTryCompileExec1211176580/fast"
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1211176580.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1211176580.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/jon/coreclr/bin/obj/Linux.x64.Debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/jon/coreclr/bin/obj/Linux.x64.Debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles 1
Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1211176580.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o
/usr/bin/clang++-3.5    -Wall -Wno-null-conversion -std=c++11    -o CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1211176580.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -c /home/jon/coreclr/bin/obj/Linux.x64.Debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCXXCompiler.cxx
Linking CXX executable cmTryCompileExec1211176580
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1211176580.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/clang++-3.5    -Wall -Wno-null-conversion -std=c++11     CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1211176580.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o  -o cmTryCompileExec1211176580 -rdynamic 
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/jon/coreclr/bin/obj/Linux.x64.Debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'


Detecting CXX compiler ABI info compiled with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/jon/coreclr/bin/obj/Linux.x64.Debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:/usr/bin/make "cmTryCompileExec1742979203/fast"
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1742979203.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1742979203.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/jon/coreclr/bin/obj/Linux.x64.Debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/jon/coreclr/bin/obj/Linux.x64.Debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles 1
Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1742979203.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.o
/usr/bin/clang++-3.5    -Wall -Wno-null-conversion -std=c++11    -o CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1742979203.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.o -c /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp
Linking CXX executable cmTryCompileExec1742979203
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1742979203.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/clang++-3.5    -Wall -Wno-null-conversion -std=c++11   -v CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1742979203.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.o  -o cmTryCompileExec1742979203 -rdynamic  
Ubuntu clang version 3.5.0-4ubuntu2~trusty2 (tags/RELEASE_350/final) (based on LLVM 3.5.0)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8.2
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9.1
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8.2
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9.1
Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Selected multilib: .;@m64
 "/usr/bin/ld" -export-dynamic -z relro --hash-style=gnu --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o cmTryCompileExec1742979203 /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/crtbegin.o -L/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8 -L/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../.. -L/usr/lib/llvm-3.5/bin/../lib -L/lib -L/usr/lib CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1742979203.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.o -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/crtend.o /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/jon/coreclr/bin/obj/Linux.x64.Debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'


Parsed CXX implicit link information from above output:
  link line regex: [^( *|.*[/\])(llvm-link-3\.5|([^/\]+-)?ld|collect2)[^/\]*( |$)]
  ignore line: [Change Dir: /home/jon/coreclr/bin/obj/Linux.x64.Debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp]
  ignore line: []
  ignore line: [Run Build Command:/usr/bin/make "cmTryCompileExec1742979203/fast"]
  ignore line: [/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1742979203.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1742979203.dir/build]
  ignore line: [make[1]: Entering directory `/home/jon/coreclr/bin/obj/Linux.x64.Debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp']
  ignore line: [/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/jon/coreclr/bin/obj/Linux.x64.Debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles 1]
  ignore line: [Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1742979203.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.o]
  ignore line: [/usr/bin/clang++-3.5    -Wall -Wno-null-conversion -std=c++11    -o CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1742979203.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.o -c /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp]
  ignore line: [Linking CXX executable cmTryCompileExec1742979203]
  ignore line: [/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1742979203.dir/link.txt --verbose=1]
  ignore line: [/usr/bin/clang++-3.5    -Wall -Wno-null-conversion -std=c++11   -v CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1742979203.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.o  -o cmTryCompileExec1742979203 -rdynamic  ]
  ignore line: [Ubuntu clang version 3.5.0-4ubuntu2~trusty2 (tags/RELEASE_350/final) (based on LLVM 3.5.0)]
  ignore line: [Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu]
  ignore line: [Thread model: posix]
  ignore line: [Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8]
  ignore line: [Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8.2]
  ignore line: [Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9]
  ignore line: [Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9.1]
  ignore line: [Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8]
  ignore line: [Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8.2]
  ignore line: [Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9]
  ignore line: [Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9.1]
  ignore line: [Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8]
  ignore line: [Candidate multilib: .]
  ignore line: [@m64]
  ignore line: [Selected multilib: .]
  ignore line: [@m64]
  link line: [ "/usr/bin/ld" -export-dynamic -z relro --hash-style=gnu --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o cmTryCompileExec1742979203 /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/crtbegin.o -L/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8 -L/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../.. -L/usr/lib/llvm-3.5/bin/../lib -L/lib -L/usr/lib CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1742979203.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.o -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/crtend.o /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o]
    arg [/usr/bin/ld] ==> ignore
    arg [-export-dynamic] ==> ignore
    arg [-zrelro] ==> ignore
    arg [--hash-style=gnu] ==> ignore
    arg [--build-id] ==> ignore
    arg [--eh-frame-hdr] ==> ignore
    arg [-m] ==> ignore
    arg [elf_x86_64] ==> ignore
    arg [-dynamic-linker] ==> ignore
    arg [/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2] ==> ignore
    arg [-o] ==> ignore
    arg [cmTryCompileExec1742979203] ==> ignore
    arg [/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o] ==> ignore
    arg [/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o] ==> ignore
    arg [/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/crtbegin.o] ==> ignore
    arg [-L/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8] ==> dir [/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8]
    arg [-L/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu] ==> dir [/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu]
    arg [-L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu] ==> dir [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu]
    arg [-L/lib/../lib64] ==> dir [/lib/../lib64]
    arg [-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu] ==> dir [/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu]
    arg [-L/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../..] ==> dir [/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../..]
    arg [-L/usr/lib/llvm-3.5/bin/../lib] ==> dir [/usr/lib/llvm-3.5/bin/../lib]
    arg [-L/lib] ==> dir [/lib]
    arg [-L/usr/lib] ==> dir [/usr/lib]
    arg [CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1742979203.dir/CMakeCXXCompilerABI.cpp.o] ==> ignore
    arg [-lstdc++] ==> lib [stdc++]
    arg [-lm] ==> lib [m]
    arg [-lgcc_s] ==> lib [gcc_s]
    arg [-lgcc] ==> lib [gcc]
    arg [-lc] ==> lib [c]
    arg [-lgcc_s] ==> lib [gcc_s]
    arg [-lgcc] ==> lib [gcc]
    arg [/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/crtend.o] ==> ignore
    arg [/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o] ==> ignore
  remove lib [gcc_s]
  remove lib [gcc]
  remove lib [gcc_s]
  remove lib [gcc]
  collapse library dir [/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8] ==> [/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8]
  collapse library dir [/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu] ==> [/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu]
  collapse library dir [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu] ==> [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu]
  collapse library dir [/lib/../lib64] ==> [/lib64]
  collapse library dir [/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu] ==> [/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu]
  collapse library dir [/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../..] ==> [/usr/lib]
  collapse library dir [/usr/lib/llvm-3.5/bin/../lib] ==> [/usr/lib/llvm-3.5/lib]
  collapse library dir [/lib] ==> [/lib]
  collapse library dir [/usr/lib] ==> [/usr/lib]
  implicit libs: [stdc++;m;c]
  implicit dirs: [/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu;/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu;/lib64;/usr/lib;/usr/lib/llvm-3.5/lib;/lib]
  implicit fwks: []
```

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my own answer!  I just needed to find a more complete set of instructions, which I did find here:

https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/wiki/Linux-instructions

I had to run these commands:

```
echo "deb http://llvm.org/apt/trusty/ llvm-toolchain-trusty-3.6 main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/llvm.list
wget -O - http://llvm.org/apt/llvm-snapshot.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
```

Then for good measure:

```
sudo apt-get install cmake llvm-3.5 clang-3.5 lldb-3.6 lldb-3.6-dev libunwind8 libunwind8-dev gettext
```

I was then able to successfully execute the build.sh in coreclr...and an hour later it was finished.

Thanks me!